# AngularJs Select ng-model not working with foreign key value

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

Let's say I have a service that provides a list of objects that I want to load as options in a `<select>` element.

The service method is `myReferenceList.getCachedList()`.

It returns an array of objects of the following structure:

```
[
  {
    ReferenceId: "guid-1234", 
    ReferenceName: "some string",
    SomeRandomRefField: 5  
  },
  // etc...
]
```

In my controller I have a `$scope.dataRow` variable defined like so:

```
$scope.dataRow = {
   ReferenceIdFk: "guid-2345",
   // etc...
}
```

I want to load the select option list with data from `myReferenceList.getCachedList()`, with the displayed text coming from `ReferenceName` and the non-visible value coming from `ReferenceId`.

I want to hook this select item up to `$scope.dataRow.ReferenceIdFk` something like this:

```
ng-model="dataRow.ReferenceIdFk"
```

When all is said and done, and the data is loaded into `$scope.dataRow.ReferenceIdFk`, the select element should hold the selected object's `ReferenceId` value. When a user selects a different item in the select list, the value in `$scope.dataRow.ReferenceIdFk` should automagically get changed to the correct value.

How can I get this to work?

Loading the values into the select list is easy.   Getting the automagic binding to the underlying data value in `$scope.dataRow.ReferenceIdFk` just doesn't seem to work.

Obviously, I can hand-jam in some procedural code to make this binding work, but I'm trying to understand how to declaratively make it work using angular features.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` provides a micro-syntax to declare how to map objects in an array to display value and the selected result:

Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage) provides the full syntax, but for your case the following should work:

```
<select ng-model="dataRow.ReferenceIdFk" 
  ng-options="i.ReferenceId as i.ReferenceName for i in myReferenceList.getCachedList()">
</select>
```

In a nutshell, the microsyntax is:

```
"<valueExp> as <displayExp> for <itemAlias> in <arrayExp>"
```

where:

- `arrayExp`: is the expression that returns an array of values
- `itemAlias`: is the alias for each item in an array; can be whatever you want
- `displayExp`: a string expression that is used for each label; uses the `itemAlias`
- `valueEx`: an expression whose value is assigned to ngModel-bound variable; uses `itemAlias`, and can return either a property of the item (`itemAlias.prop as`) or the item itself (`itemAlias as`)

Comment: I tried this syntax already.  This correctly builds the select/option html except that the right option value is not selected, and dataRow.ReferenceIdFk does not get loaded when the user picks an option.   I'll try again on Monday...

Comment: Same behavior as before.  The option tags are look good but the first option is selected instead of the correct on based on the ReferenceIdFk value.    When I pick an option in the drop down list the value of ReferenceIdFk is changed to a blank or null value, not the value I picked.

Comment: @davidwendelken, hard to say without seeing your code. The fact that the first option is selected (rather than being blank) means that the value in `ngModel` (whether it's `Id` or the actual object) matches that of the first option's `valueExp`. The change to `null` is puzzling. Are you sure that you are not altering `dataRow` or `dataRow.ReferenceIdFk` in same way following the selection?